# Doesn't even get into the method. Error "invoke virtual method java.lang.list on a null object reference"

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm creating a timetable app, using an SQLite database and it was working fine, until i read an article on good coding practises. 
I had a DatabaseHelper file with over 1000+ lines of code due to including every create, read, update and delete statement in there. I went away and edited my code so that each table has a separate class for it's CRUD statements, but now it doesn't work.
Everytime I run the app, it crashes and i get the error

`invoke virtual method java.lang.list Database.SschoolDay_CRUD on a null object reference`
(90% like that. I'm afraid I wont be able to get the specific error for at least 24 hours, but I can't access a pc with the permissions to run the app until tomorrow afternoon.)

I don't want to roll back to the hell of a 1000 line+ class.
So, after some detective work, I've worked out the specific line where it is going wrong.

My `DatabaseHelper` runs this method

```
 SschoolDay_CRUD sschool_day;
List<SschoolDay_model_class> s;
public List<SschoolDay_model_class> getAllSSchoolDays() {
            Log.v("Does it get here?", "YES");

            s = sschool_day.getAllSSchoolDays();
            Log.v("Does it get here?", "YES2");

            return s;
        }
```

I want this then to run the `getAllSSchoolDays()` method within the `SschoolDay_CRUD` class, which looks like this:

```
/*
 * getting all SchoolDays
 */
public List<SschoolDay_model_class> getAllSSchoolDays() {
    Log.v("Peep", "BEFORE");
    List<SschoolDay_model_class> school_day = new ArrayList<SschoolDay_model_class>();
    Log.v("Peep", "after");
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SSCHOOL_DAY;

    Log.e(DatabaseHelper.LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            SschoolDay_model_class sdy = new SschoolDay_model_class();
            sdy.setSchool_day_id(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY_ID))));
            sdy.setSchool_day(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY)));
            sdy.setUsed(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY_USED)));
            sdy.setNo_of_lessons(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY_NO_OF_LESSONS)));

            // adding to SchoolDay list
            school_day.add(sdy);
        } while (c.moveToNext());

    }
    return school_day;
}
```

The log does not even display "BEFORE". Therefore it seems to be the

```
public List<SschoolDay_model_class> getAllSSchoolDays() {
```

For extra information, the class `SschoolDay_model_class` looks like this:

```
package Database;

public class SschoolDay_model_class {

long school_day_id;
String school_day;
String used;
int no_of_lessons;

//constructors
public SschoolDay_model_class() {
}

public SschoolDay_model_class (long school_day_id, String school_day, String used, int no_of_lessons){
    this.school_day_id = school_day_id;
    this.school_day = school_day;
    this.used = used;
    this.no_of_lessons = no_of_lessons;

}


//setters
public void setSchool_day_id(long school_day_id){
    this.school_day_id = school_day_id;
}

public void setSchool_day(String school_day){
    this.school_day = school_day;
}

public void setUsed(String used) {
    this.used = used;
}

public void setNo_of_lessons(int no_of_lessons){
    this.no_of_lessons = no_of_lessons;
}

//getters
public long getSchool_day_id() {
    return this.school_day_id;
}

public String getschool_day() {
    return this.school_day;
}

public String getUsed() {
    return this.used;
}

public int getNo_of_lessons() {
    return this.no_of_lessons;
}
```

}

Edit:
SschoolDay_CRUD class is this:

```
       package Database;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;


   import android.content.ContentValues;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
   import android.util.Log;

   public class SschoolDay_CRUD extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
/*
 * School Days will never be deleted, only set to used or not, which will determine their use.
 * Therefore I have not written a delete statement for school day.
 */

/*
 * Creating a School Day
 */


public long createSSchoolDay(SschoolDay_model_class school_day) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY, school_day.getschool_day());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY_USED, school_day.getUsed());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY_NO_OF_LESSONS, school_day.getNo_of_lessons());

    // insert row
    long sschool_day_id = db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SSCHOOL_DAY, null, values);

    return sschool_day_id;
    }

/*
 * getting all SchoolDays
 */
public List<SschoolDay_model_class> getAllSSchoolDays() {
    Log.v("Peep", "BEFORE");
    List<SschoolDay_model_class> school_day = new ArrayList<SschoolDay_model_class>();
    Log.v("Peep", "after");
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SSCHOOL_DAY;

    Log.e(DatabaseHelper.LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            SschoolDay_model_class sdy = new SschoolDay_model_class();
            sdy.setSchool_day_id(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY_ID))));
            sdy.setSchool_day(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY)));
            sdy.setUsed(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY_USED)));
            sdy.setNo_of_lessons(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY_NO_OF_LESSONS)));

            // adding to SchoolDay list
            school_day.add(sdy);
        } while (c.moveToNext());

    }
    return school_day;
}

/*
 * Updating a SchoolDay
 */
public int updatesSchoolDay(SschoolDay_model_class school_day) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY, school_day.getschool_day());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY_USED, school_day.getUsed());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY_NO_OF_LESSONS, school_day.getNo_of_lessons());
    // updating row
    return db.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SSCHOOL_DAY, values, DatabaseHelper.KEY_SSCHOOL_DAY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(school_day.getSchool_day_id()) });
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    // creating required tables
    db.execSQL(DatabaseHelper.CREATE_TABLE_SSCHOOL_DAY);
    db.execSQL(DatabaseHelper.CREATE_TABLE_SPERIODS);
    db.execSQL(DatabaseHelper.CREATE_TABLE_SLESSON);
    db.execSQL(DatabaseHelper.CREATE_TABLE_SHOMEWORK);
    db.execSQL(DatabaseHelper.CREATE_TABLE_SEXAM);
    db.execSQL(DatabaseHelper.CREATE_TABLE_SLESSON_TIME);
    //creating revision tables
    db.execSQL(DatabaseHelper.CREATE_TABLE_RREVISION_DAY);
    db.execSQL(DatabaseHelper.CREATE_TABLE_RSESSION_PERIOD);
    db.execSQL(DatabaseHelper.CREATE_TABLE_RSESSION);
    db.execSQL(DatabaseHelper.CREATE_TABLE_RSESSION_TIME);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // on upgrade drop older tables
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SSCHOOL_DAY);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SPERIODS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SLESSON);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SHOMEWORK);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SEXAM);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SLESSON_TIME);

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_RREVISION_DAY);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_RSESSION_PERIOD);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_RSESSION);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_RSESSION_TIME);
    // create new tables
    onCreate(db);
        }
public  SschoolDay_CRUD(Context context) {
    super(context, DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null, DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

EDIT: new error! (yay)
now I'm getting
...considering rolling it back to the 1000+ line, at least that worked !!

```
03-13 12:32:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(2374): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
```

because of this line :
`SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();`

here is the constructor for the DatabaseHelper:

```
    public Context DBHContext;

 public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {


    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    DBHContext = context;
}
```

I then use DBHContext in the initialization of the SschoolDay_CRUD

```
SschoolDay_CRUD sschool_day = new SschoolDay_CRUD(DBHContext);
```

Answer (score 1):

From Your code it seems, that Your `sschool_day` is not initialized at this time:

```
     s = sschool_day.getAllSSchoolDays();
```

You have to initialize `SschoolDay_CRUD sschool_day;` before calling `getAllSSchoolDays();`

Your initializing should look like this:

```
    SschoolDay_CRUD sschool_day = new SschoolDay_CRUD(yourContext);
   List<SschoolDay_model_class> s;
     public List<SschoolDay_model_class> getAllSSchoolDays() {
        Log.v("Does it get here?", "YES");

        s = sschool_day.getAllSSchoolDays();
        Log.v("Does it get here?", "YES2");

        return s;
    }
```

Comment: @Yazan, no what I meant was, sschool_day is not initialized, that´s the problem. So calling a function from an Object that is not initialized will throw this exception...

Comment: You can´t initialize it to null. This will also throw this exception. It has to be a valid object...

Comment: what is  SschoolDay_CRUD ? Can You show this class?

Comment: added the SschoolDay_CRUD class

Comment: awesome, thanks. Um I'm now getting a problem when using either getContext() or getApplicationContext(), using either eclipse just tells me theyre undefined

Comment: make a constructor for Your database helper with Context as parameter. make this context a global one in DatabaseHelper. ....

Comment: added an edit to the question with the new error im getting! Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Please show where do You pass the context to new SschoolDay_CRUD(). You´ve passed the wrong context. Do You initilaize this in an Activity or in another class?

Comment: I initialise the DBHContext within the DatabaseHelper Class, and get it from the constructor method. I then use the DBHContext to initialize the Sschoolday_CRUD. Added more code to the question to show this,

Comment: I see Your problem...don´t use a second context. The context is automatically initialized in the super() method from the constructor. Delete DBHContext, and another question, from where do You take the context? Are You calling it from inside an activity?

Comment: the context is got whenever i initialize the databasehelper in another class... eg "db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());".

Comment: getApplicationContext() is not everytime the correct solution. If You are using an activity, just use "this"....

Comment: Tried using just "this" and it threw up the same error. :-(

Comment: can You send me the project? I think it will be the best if I can see the complete code....

Comment: sure. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5D113EDC76B24988!655&authkey=!AA9KQV_yoNmdhGE&ithint=folder%2cclasspath

Comment: ok, where do You use SschoolDay_CRUD, in which class? Sorry, it´s a huge content with many classes, can´t find where You use it :)  ...

Comment: in the Database Helper class. :)

Comment: ok, got it. You should initialze SschoolDay_CRUD inside the constructor with SschoolDay_CRUD sschool_day = new SschoolDay_CRUD(context); . Don´t use the DBHContext...

Comment: I didn't check. Afraid i couldnt waste anymore time on it :-(

Comment: i'm on a verrrrry tight deadline.